# Compare 1 string with a cell array of strings with indexes (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, similarity, cell-array

I have 1 string and 1 cell array of srings :

```
  F = 'ABCD'
  R = {'ACBD','CDAB','CABD'};
```

I would like to compare the string F with all of the strings in R as follows: F(1)='A' and R{1}(1)='A', we will count 1 ( because they have the same value 'A') , F(2)='B' and R{1}(2)='C' we will count 0 ( because they have different values)...and like that until the end of all strings.

We will get `same = 2` , `dif = 2` for this 'ABCD' and 'ACBD'.

How can I compare F with all the elements in R in the above rule and get the total(same) and total(dif) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all strings in `R` has the same length as `F` you can use `cellfun`:

```
same = cellfun( @(r) sum(F==r), R )
```

Results with

```
2     0     1
```

That is, the `same` value per string in `R`. If you want `dif`:

```
dif = numel(F)-same;
```

If you want the totals:

```
tot_same = sum(same);
tot_dif = sum(dif);
```